# Mixed Content. При отправке формы

Tags: php, html, http, https

При отправке формы, в консоль выводит ошибку:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://site/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure form action 'http://site/forms/callback/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

При этом, на форме, в action записан относительный путь

```
<form action="/forms/callback/index.php" method="POST">
```

На странице больше нету подобных ссылок

Comment: А форма у вас не ajax отправляется? Скрипты проверяли?

Comment: @Visman Да, все таки дело в ajax, сайт на bitrix.
Вы случайно не подскажете, где находится в bitrix файл с ajax запросом, который отправляет на http?

Comment: Попробуйте указать абсолютный путь: //site.org/....../forms/callback/index.php